# What component may this be?

Tags: identification, components, fuses

What component is this? They have a temperature printed, and a part code, but both are pretty much erased in the purple part. The orange one is a bit more readable, but not much. I think they may be resistors, but I'm not sure.

[image: Unknown components]

This is the information I can read from both parts:

- Orange: T1 = 169 °C; D167PHMP
- Purple: 184 °C

The measured resistance on both seems to be about 3-5 Ω.

Comment: [A corresponding meta post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6697/should-we-keep-component-identification-questions/6709#6709). The canonical may or may not be *[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines)*. (Shouldn't this be reflected in the tag wiki?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those are [thermal fuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff#Thermal_fuse). They break the connection permanently once a certain temperature is reached to protect devices from overheating and possibly causing fire.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Nice to have around, then...

Comment: Is there a general reason for the U bend? Like thermal expansion or something like that or it just happen to be this way for unknown circuit specific reasons (geometric constraint...)

Comment: @SredniVashtar They don't come like that when new so most likely it's application specific, being shaped like that to fit inside some kind of retention in the device.

Comment: Maybe the thermal fuse had to be touching a certain part of the device (like in an electrical heating plate, they sometime touche the plates), to make them as useful as possible.

Comment: Notice how the connection is crimped rather than soldered, to avoid opening the fuse before it has even been used.